# Как сравнить значения в массиве и вывести дополнительное

Tags: php

Форма передает методом POST 50 чекбоксов:

```
<input name="b[]" type='checkbox' value='Finance'><br>
<input name="b[]" type='checkbox' value='Finance2'><br>
<input name="b[]" type='checkbox' value='Finance3'><br><br>
```

// Выбираем отмеченные и считаем

```
$arr_b = $_POST['b'];
$count_b = count($arr_b);
$cheked_b = implode("<br>",$arr_b);
```

Нужно сравнить и подставить в переменную $cheked_b_code значения
Например если

```
Finance это 'T4'
Finance2 это 'Q6'
Finance3 это 'R4'
```

Чтоб в $cheked_b_code попали эти данные T4 Q6 R4 в таком формате
`$cheked_b_code = "'T4','Q6','R4'"`
Обязательно чтоб в начале и конце небыло запятых
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вам сначала нужны данные для соответствия. Если все делать просто, их можно определить в массиве:

```
$values = [
   'Finance'=>'T4',
   'Finance2'=>'Q6',
   ...
];
```

Далее, получить массив значений полей соответственно тому, что выбрали в чекбоксах:

```
foreach ($arr_b as $val){
    $result[]=$values[$val];
}
```

И в итоге склеить результаты из массива запятыми:

```
$cheked_b_code = implode(',',$result);
```

Полагаю как то так, если я все правильно понял.